# clearing float height

Tags: css, css-float, overflow

http://jsfiddle.net/yN2Ky/2/show/

form page: http://jsfiddle.net/wbRBj/2/

The problem is that content of `mainarea` changes on the fly so `overflow:hidden;` on that `contentarea` doesn't work.

I want...

`sidebar.height=max(mainarea.height,sidebar.height)=contentarea.height=mainarea.height`

Any suggestions?

Tip: try to search with keyword "Εξεταστική".

The code above works fine for pages that haven't change mainarea/sidebar content (and height of them) on the fly...

[image: googlecss]

It seem's that google make clear into cse div, but somehow, this properties are disabled
**image from ie F12 mode

Comment: have you tried clearfix?

Comment: if you mean this http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html no..
But if you mean do add a class after contentarea that has clear:both, yes i try it..
no effects

Comment: Pff, it gonna crazy me..
Wtf should i try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Option #1

1. Remove the border from `#sidebar`
2. Add a right border to `#mainarea`

---

```
#mainarea
{
    /* all the other styles */

    border-right:1px double #c1c0a8;
}
```

### Option #2

[Equal-height Columns](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks)

[See my demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u8kd2/)

### Option #3

[Faux Columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/)

Comment: well that's not a accepted answer because contentarea has     width:990px; and background image beside it (repeated-y)
if i make two images for background, this is a accepted answer..
But even i do that, i want sidebar-height:100% for background image

Comment: Whoa whoa whoa... background image? I saw nothing about that.

Comment: Updated to include two more options.

Comment: Option #2 is just fine..
Option #3 is a bit compicated, so i will use #2
thx sir